# CoreBluetooth long characteristics CBATTErrorDomain Code=11 "The attribute is not long

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have a characteristic value which contains the large set of data (~200 Bytes)

**Peripheral**

```
_ch = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:_chUUID
                                      properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
                                      value:nil                                                                 
                                      permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable ];
```

When this value is requested, the didRecieveRequest callback is called:

```
-(void) peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveReadRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request {

if ([request.characteristic.UUID isEqual:_chUUID]) {
    if (request.offset > _data.length) {
        [_peripheralManager respondToRequest:request withResult:CBATTErrorInvalidOffset];
        return;
    }
    else {
        // Return the data
        request.value = [_data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(request.offset, _data.length - request.offset)];
        [_peripheralManager respondToRequest:request withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];
    }
}
```

This is is pretty much from Apple's example.

On the Central side, when `didUpdateValueCorCharacteristic:` callback is called, i get the error

```
Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=11 "The attribute is not long."
```

I know that I could use the Notify mechanism to chunk the data myself, as shown at the WWDC 2012. But that is not an option as I am not in charge of the Central code.

I would assume that `didReceiveReadRequest:` should be called more than once (with a increasing offset) as CB Framework should take care of the chunking, right? Do I miss something here?

Cheers

Comment: How many times is your `didReceiveReadRequest` callback called? What chunks of data do you send over? You seem to be using the API the way it is designed so the issue will rely in the details somewhere.

Comment: @allprog didReceiveReadRequest: is called only once.